# How to create a package using records and stored procedures? oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have never used oracle (only t-sql)

I need create a package which must to have records and use this record in two stored procedures

/*I have never used a package
I dont know how to invoke (call or execut the package)
I need to call it in a third system for update or insert  a person)
*/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_CRM_INSERTUPDATE_PERSONAS IS

/*
this must to  create a stored procedure for insert and update  a table
*/
declare
  TYPE typePersona IS RECORD (
    varNombre: VARCHAR2(200);
    varApellidoPaterno : VARCHAR2(200);
    varApellidoMaterno : VARCHAR2(200);
    varRFC : VARCHAR2(200);
    varIfe : VARCHAR2(200);
    varFechaNacimiento : DATE;
    varNumeroHijos : NUMBER;
    varIdSituacion : NUMBER;
    varIdActividad : NUMBER;
    varIdPais : NUMBER;
    varIdGenero : VARCHAR2(200);
    varIdEstadoCivil : NUMBER;
    varIdLocalidad : NUMBER;
    varIdPersona : NUMBER;
    varCURP : VARCHAR2(200);
    varIdTipoPersona : VARCHAR2(200);
    varCalle : VARCHAR2(200);
    varNumeroExterior : VARCHAR2(200);
    varNumeroPiso : VARCHAR2(200);
    varNumeroDepartamento : VARCHAR2(200);
    )

END;
```

Comment: If as you said you've never used PL/SQL what makes you think you need to define a record to modify a table? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: i need create a record inside a package and use this record for insert/update the person table

Comment: the goal is "create a package for insert/update package"

Comment: You can just do that (insert or update)  with a MERGE statement.

Comment: Could you really not find any [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm) or [examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%2Bto%2Bdeclare%2Ba%2Brecord%2Btype%2Bin%2Bpl%2Bsql) for PL/SQL? It looks like you've just tried some T-SQL in Oracle and come here when it didn't work first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to insert/update records in a table, you probably do not need to define a record, but you can find easier ways.

However, about the creation and the usage of a package, your header declaration has some errors, just fixed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_CRM_INSERTUPDATE_PERSONAS IS

  TYPE typePersona IS RECORD (
    varNombre VARCHAR2(200),
    varApellidoPaterno  VARCHAR2(200),
    varApellidoMaterno  VARCHAR2(200),
    varRFC  VARCHAR2(200),
    varIfe  VARCHAR2(200),
    varFechaNacimiento  DATE,
    varNumeroHijos  NUMBER,
    varIdSituacion  NUMBER,
    varIdActividad  NUMBER,
    varIdPais  NUMBER,
    varIdGenero  VARCHAR2(200),
    varIdEstadoCivil  NUMBER,
    varIdLocalidad  NUMBER,
    varIdPersona  NUMBER,
    varCURP  VARCHAR2(200),
    varIdTipoPersona  VARCHAR2(200),
    varCalle  VARCHAR2(200),
    varNumeroExterior  VARCHAR2(200),
    varNumeroPiso  VARCHAR2(200),
    varNumeroDepartamento  VARCHAR2(200)
    );

    procedure someProcIn(pIn IN typePersona);
    procedure someProcInOut(pInOut IN OUT typePersona);

END;
```

But a package header does not do anything without a body, where you write your procedures; for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body PKG_CRM_INSERTUPDATE_PERSONAS IS

    procedure someProcIn(pIn IN typePersona) is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line(pIn.varNombre);
    end;

    procedure someProcInOut(pInOut IN OUT typePersona) is
    begin
        pInOut.varNombre := 'varNombre value';
    end;

END;
```

Once your package is created, you can call its procedures and functions ( you call a procedure or a function contained in a package, not the package itself) this way:

```
declare
    myVar  PKG_CRM_INSERTUPDATE_PERSONAS.typePersona;
begin    
    --
    PKG_CRM_INSERTUPDATE_PERSONAS.someProcInOut(myVar);
    --
    PKG_CRM_INSERTUPDATE_PERSONAS.someProcIn(myVar); 
end;
```

Comment: Aleksej, if the structure of the record is the same as structure of the row it can be simplified - there would be no need for record type declaration at all. [Here is an example](http://rextester.com/KQNR17007). But if as OP says data comes from some third party system, oracle record type would probable needed to be turned into schema level object type and mapped accordingly. But we do not know for sure hot the process works there, OP doesn't want to share ;-)